# Replayability of Events in Event Sourced System with EDA

Tags: architecture, cqrs, event-sourcing, eda

I have 2 CQRS+ES Event Driven System (EDS), they both share the same EventStore and my EventStore also streams its data being like an EventBus. Currently both EDS subscribes to the same EventBus but are listening to different events.

When EDS2 publishes an *OrderCreatedEvent*, I need EDS1 to pick that event and perform some of its own domain logic. I believe this should be done by sending its own domain Command.

Sample Implementation of the *OrderCreatedEvent* handler in EDS1:

```
public class OrderCreatedEventHandler: INotificationHandler<OrderCreatedEvent>
{
    public Task Handle(OrderCreatedEvent orderEvent, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
            await _mediator.Send(new SendShippingNotificationCommand(order.Id));
            await _mediator.Send(new SendOrderEmailCommand(order.Id));
    }
}
```

With the above implementation and architecture design, how am i able to replay events in EDS1? assuming i need to replay to compute projection. Because each time i replay the events, the *OrderCreatedEvent* handler will be called and sends out the 2 commands again. Is there any suggestions to overcome this?

Comment: I guess OrderCreatedEventHandler sends some notifications, while there is second (or more) OrderCreatedEvent handler that computes projection.
You'll handle that by bootstraping replay with OrderCreatedEvent handler that handles computing projection leaving out notifications handler.

Comment: There is a mixing understand of event sourcing and messaging here. According to his exclusive stream of Domain Events, the events from Event Store are characteristic of event-sourcing for rebuilding the Aggregate Root state. If you publish those events to the bus for a reactive integration, it does not mean you can replay them because the integration can not repeat. The event as a message is like a request. Take a look at this project where those principles are applied: https://github.com/AntonioFalcaoJr/EventualShop